# AtlasMap can't get target document from .adm file imported into java

Tags: atlasmap

I imported the target xml file into the AtlasMap Data Mapper UI as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns:XmlOE xmlns:ns="http://atlasmap.io/xml/test/v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ns:Address>
        <ns:addressLine1>1040 Notexisting St</ns:addressLine1>
        <ns:zipCode>01886</ns:zipCode>
    </ns:Address>
    <ns:Contact>
        <ns:fullName>Totton</ns:fullName>
        <ns:phoneNumber>123-456-7890</ns:phoneNumber>
        <ns:zipCode>01886</ns:zipCode>
    </ns:Contact>
</ns:XmlOE>
```

Then I exported it to *.adm file and after that importing it to the eclipse.
There is the log:
[log_and_code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8vv2.png)

I run main class and get errors.
If I use *.adm file from example project and re-export it from AtlasMap Data Mapper UI, it work well.

Answer (score 0):

> The answer from @igarashitm
>
> You'd need to copy `Document ID` of the imported target document from
> UI and use it as a key to retrieve a target document. Or simply use
> `getDefaultTargetDocumentIO`. When you import a document, an auto
> generated `Document ID` is assigned which has GUID suffix. So the
> target document is no longer `XMLInstanceSource`.

In my case `getDefaultTargetDocument()` works well.
I believe it is the [Document ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KubyH.png) he is referring to.